# Automating user password creation and User privileges restriction in solaris 8

Tags: scripting, solaris

I have couple of questions. Here is the first one

1. We are trying to automate the creation of a user in solaris 8. We provide a default password and then force the user to change the password at first login by using the command

   ```
   passwd -f $user
   ```

but the issue is we have to type the password two times so as to confirm it. I have tried automating it using the following command

```
echo $password | password -f $user
```

Nothing happens with this command.
Please is there any other way of doing the same?

Comment: You should only ask one question per question.

Comment: Alright, sorry thought since its related i can ask both together

Comment: On Linux the solution would be something like `usermod -p '$1$9KcQut9K$j7Sf5mEouKDjmmYKsiRcV/' username`, but unfortunately it appears that is [not supported on Solaris](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/821-1462/usermod-1m.html). That doesn't mean it is impossible to do it on Solaris, only that I don't know how to do it.

Comment: I have retracted my close vote. If the question does end up getting closed, I will vote to reopen.

Comment: @kasperd Bro i dont understand what you mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can easily do what you want to do on such an ancient<sup>1</sup> system.

I don't think this will work but you could try

```
echo "password\npassword" | passwd user
```

You could try to use the [expect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect) utility. This will do what you want and there are plenty of example scripts on how to change a password using it. The trouble is it may not be natively part of Solaris 8.

Another option is for you to generate the password hashes using an program that calculates [crypt](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-0627/6j9vhfmnj/index.html)(newpass,salt)<sup>2</sup> and then change the password field in the appropriate file.

---

<sup>1</sup>Your big issue here and with your other questions is that Solaris 8 is so ancient that even the internet is forgetting it. It was superseded by Solaris 9 in about 2003 and Oracle put it into extended support in 2012. Effectively, unless you have extended support you are unsupported and should not be using it in a business environment.

If you really need Solaris because you have ancient application programs then you should upgrade to at least Solaris 10. I'm guessing that the hardware you're running this Solaris 8 installation on is SPARC. The good news is that SPARC systems are binary compatible to you should be able to run your Solaris 8 binaries on newer SPARC hardware and a supported OS.

<sup>2</sup>  No, I don't know of a program to do this on Solaris 8. If you have perl then

```
perl -e 'print crypt("YourPasswd", "salt"),"\n"'
```

may work.

Comment: Thanks bro have already tried the echo command , doesn't work. The crypt thing, i have no idea, will take a look at it later. Thanks anyways.

Comment: The password hash does not necessarily have to be computed on the Solaris machine. One just have to use a salt format supported by Solaris 8. I would test an MD5 based hash first, and if that isn't supported try DES based.

Comment: This answer would be better if it included a recommendation on how to change the password field in the appropriate file.

Comment: @kasperd, Please feel free to edit one in. I chose not to because the standard utilities that I use today are somewhat different than the 'same' ones on S8. Awk certainly isn't the same as the one we have today, I recall some version(s) of Solaris had nawk but don't recall how or what the comparabilities are.  Similarly sed is entirely different to what I'm used to these days. I wouldn't like to put up a command I didn't have a reasonable idea would work largely due to the sniping that goes on here ;)

Comment: @Iain I have no Solaris system to test it on. And I would say a sensible recommendation should go through standard tools for accessing the passwd file, such that identifying the correct file path and lock handling is taken care of. I don't know how to do that on Solaris, and the documentation I could find online was not helpful.

Comment: I'm not sure what 'standard tools' are available on Solaris 8, `passwd --stdin` - nope, `chpasswd` - nope, `expect` (probably) nope, `mkpasswd` - nope, `usermod -p` nope  Any others ?